# python code for power ball lottery

Tags: python

I don't know how to write a code for the question below

> Write a Python function, call it `Powerball()`, that will return a legitimate Powerball lottery number. Recall that a Powerball number consists of 5 random numbers from 1 to 69, followed by a random number, known as the Powerball, from 1 to 26. In returning the numbers, the first 5 numbers should be in order, followed by the Powerball. Here is an example: `4, 13, 31, 36, 52, 8`. You may use a list to return the numbers, like `[4, 13, 31, 36, 52, 8]`.

Comment: If you want to learn how to write Python code, starting with an introductory Python tutorial would be a good approach.

Comment: Unfortuantely, SO is not what you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import random as r

```
def Powerball():
    result = []
    for i in range(5):
        number = r.randint(1,69)
        while (number in result):
            number = r.randint(1,69)
        result.append(number)
    result.sort()
    result.append(r.randint(1,26))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = Powerball()        
    print result
```

This code returns first five unique random numbers from 1 to 69 in ascending order followed by a random number form 1 to 26.

Comment: I got one more question. would u mind help me one more question please?

Comment: Write a Python function, called it strHist(x), that will print a histogram of the characters in string x, including space. Let's use character '*' to show the count. For example, strHist('this is really interesting') should print the following:

***
a *
e ***
g *
h *
i ****
l ** n ** r **
s *** t *** y *